# Partition table created using 'CREATE TABLE AS'

Tags: postgresql

How do we partition a table created using the `CREATE TABLE AS` command in PostgreSQL. I tried the following:

`CREATE TABLE schema.table2 AS TABLE schema.table1 PARTITION BY LIST(col1)`

but it gives this error:
`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "PARTITION"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible.

[`CREATE TABLE AS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtableas.html) is different from [`CREATE TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) and only supports a subset of features for the latter.